# build_iphone.sh: line 52: /Users/.../pocketsphinx-master/configure: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, sh, macos-mojave, arm64, cmusphinx

I'm on macOS Mojave in terminal, and I'm getting an error that says no such file or directory for the directory ".../pocketsphinx-master/configure" when I run build_iphone.sh, which I got from this repository: [cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-ios-demo](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-ios-demo).

The instructions for pocketsphinx found at this repository -- [cmusphinx/pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx) gives [these instructions to use pocketsphinx with Xcode](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx#xcode-installation-for-iphone). Here's part of what it says, which I don't understand:

> Pocketsphinx uses the standard unix autogen system, you can build pocketsphinx with automake given you already built sphinxbase You just need to pass correct configure arguments, set compiler path, set sysroot and other options. After you build the code you need to import dylib file into your project and you also need to configure includes for your project to find sphinxbase headers.

Here is what my terminal on my Mac mini looks like:

```
Daniels-Mac-mini:pocketsphinx-master shinehah$ sh build_iphone.sh
building arm64...
build_iphone.sh: line 52: /Users/shinehah/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-master/configure: No such file or directory
```

I created that directory, but I still get the same error message. What do I need to put in that directory?

In build_iphone.sh, line 52, it says:

```
--host="${HOST_TYPE}" \
```

Here is the code segment it is from:

```
$CWD/configure 
--host="${HOST_TYPE}" // line 52
--prefix="$DEST/$ARCH" 
--without-lapack 
--without-python 
--with-sphinxbase="$SPHINXBASE_DIR" 
|| exit 1
```

Comment: Complete shot in the dark, but try running `NOCONFIGURE=1 ./autogen.sh`.

Comment: @Siguza What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Run autotools with the appropriate flags to generate `configure`, the `Makefile`, etc. At least the code on GitHub has such a script...

Comment: @Siguza I'm unfamilear with autotools. Is that a set of commands run on terminal? I'm on a Mac mini using macOS Mojave. What script are you talking about on which GitHub repository?

Comment: @Siguza I added more content in the original post. I added what the instructions at the pocketsphinx repository said. Could you explain that to me?